# Is there a way to remove negative traits?

Tags: mass-effect-andromeda

One of my strike team members just failed and got a negative trait called Outlaw Hysteria, which penalizes him when facing outlaws in a mission.

If I send him on some easy bronze missions with outlaws will there be a chance for him to lose his negative trait?

Comment: Don't think you can remove them. Not certain. Some searching found this quote on [a forum](https://www.reddit.com/r/MEandromeda/comments/61j9e7/apex_team_negative_traits/): "I currently have 3 positive traits and 9 negative traits on my suicide gold squad. pretty sure you cant get rid of them since one of the positive traits is same as negative. i have 5 positive traits on my most successful team" Sounds like he has negative and positive traits that cancel each other out, but the traits remain anyway.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, there isn't. You can retire a squad using the retire option but this will remove the squad from your allocation, freeing up the ability to recruit a new squad.

Comment: does that refund the credits used to buy the squad?

Comment: No it does not: http://bsn.boards.net/thread/5742/retiring-strike-team

Comment: Nope (just deleted a strike team...)